# Dropbox doesn't react to clicks in tray

Tags: dropbox, windows-10

I am using Dropbox on Windows 10.  When I either left-click or right-click the Dropbox icon in the tray, nothing happens.  Is this normal?  If not, how can I fix it?  If yes, how can I access the Dropbox settings?

On OS X, which I'm more used to, clicking Dropbox in the menu bar brings up a small menu.

I am using Dropbox on Windows 10.  I tried updating Dropbox 3.8 to 3.9 beta to see if it would fix this, but it didn't.

Otherwise Dropbox functions correctly. A double-click on the tray icon brings up the folder, it syncs properly and the tray icon shows the status as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 with HiDPI monitor.

I've found two environment variables `QT_HIGHDPI_AWARE=1` and `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` in system. After removing these environment variables Dropbox UI appears on click.

Comment: You had ‘‘the sample problem‘‘?  Do you mean ‘‘the same problem‘‘?

Comment: @Scott, yes you are right. Fixed.

Comment: This also worked for me, been bugging me for ages!

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename/delete  this variable to get the right mouse button to work:

`QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=auto`